# SQL Group By Column With Latest Date

Tags: sql

I Have a table of following column name 
where we have date multiple bin have multiple date  with 30-sec date slot 
I need to pull data based on last entry respect to bin

Suppose  `1990025I` have 100 entry for today only when I query I need last enter record when I do get find All Entry group by bin am not getting a proper result

For base one Single  Bin Query

```
select * from battery_data where tcu_date_ist =(
SELECT MAX(tcu_date_ist) FROM battery_data WHERE bin='1990051I');
```

***How i get All Bin  Group Query And i also Need  `latitude`, `longitude` Column in it***

```
SELECT  latitude, longitude,  bin,created_date
        FROM public.battery_data  
        group by latitude, longitude,  bin  ,created_date
        ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

Output Am getting like

```
12.966  77.5841 "1990025I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:11.984+05:30"
13.0007 77.6128 "1990074I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:11.522+05:30"
12.9567 77.68   "1990088I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:10.663+05:30"
12.9714 77.58   "1990123I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:10.45+05:30"
0       0       "1980020I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:10.151+05:30"
12.966  77.5841 "1990025I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:10.001+05:30"
13.0952 77.5949 "M10299171990132I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:09.922+05:30"
12.9936 77.7478 "1990006I"  "2019-11-18 12:53:08.718+05:30"
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (bin) *
FROM public.battery_data
ORDER BY bin, created_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter by `bin` in both the inner and outer query:

```
select bd.*
from battery_data bd
where bd.bin = '1990051I' and
      bd.tcu_date_ist = (select max(bd2.tcu_date_ist) 
                         from battery_data bd2
                         where bd2.bin = bd.bin
                        );
```

Or if you want only one row use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select bd.*
from battery_data bd
where bd.bin = '1990051I'
order by bd.tcu_date_ist desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: for one bin its working but i need all bin, I means like findALL

Comment: @gorder Linoff  am asking for one bin , I need for all bin or Group of bin

Comment: @harkeshkumar . . . Just remove `bd.bin = '1990051I' and` in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

This no ?

```
select * from battery_data where tcu_date_ist in(
SELECT MAX(tcu_date_ist) FROM battery_data group by bin);
```